# Override external library main

Tags: webpack

is it possible to override an external library javascript file?

ex:
lib-xxx has main:lib-xxx.min.js in package.json but I want to use lib-xxx.js

/hw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible with [resolve.alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias):

```
resolve: {
   alias: {
      'lib-xxx': 'path/to/lib/lib-xxx.js'
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this relative to the original?  I would rather not hard-code the full path to a node_module if I can avoid it, since that is coupled with the package manager and the location of the `node_modules` folder.  In my case, the library provides an alternative main file (sits next to the normal main file) that I want to use.  The library is installed with NPM or Yarn or whatever and Webpack has found it, I just need to point to a file next door without having to know where the street is.